# Updating serialized data in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, serialization

I have `orders` table where I have column named `cart` and data in that column are serialized from my cart.

Now I try to make order edit function for admins where they can edit orders and so far I can get my data such as `quantity` out of my serialized data.

My question is how to edit that data (in this case `quantity`) in my `cart` column without messing with the rest of data in it?

here is my update function (still nothing about quantity):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'payment_id'=>'nullable',
            'orderstatus_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'address_id' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

        $order = Order::where('id',$id)->first();
        $order->payment_id = $request->input('payment_id');
        $order->orderstatus_id = $request->input('orderstatus_id');
        $order->address_id = $request->input('address_id');

        $order->save();

        return redirect()->route('orders.index',
            $order->id)->with('success',
            'Order updated successfully.');
    }
```

and here is how I show my order quantity in my `order.edit` page:

`function`

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);
        $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
        $statuses = Orderstatus::all();
        $addresses = Address::where('user_id', $order->user_id)->get();
        return view('admin.orders.edit', compact('order', 'statuses', 'addresses'));
    }
```

`blade`

```
<div class="row mt-20">
   @foreach($order->cart as $item)
     <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ Form::label('quantity', 'Quantity') }}
        {{ Form::text('quantity', $item['quantity'], array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
     </div><!--end col-md-4-->
   @endforeach
</div><!--end row-->
```

Thanks.

## update

sample of my serialized code

```
O:32:"Darryldecode\Cart\CartCollection":1:{s:8:"�*�items";a:1:{i:29;O:32:"Darryldecode\Cart\ItemCollection":2:{s:9:"�*�config";a:4:{s:14:"format_numbers";b:0;s:8:"decimals";i:0;s:9:"dec_point";s:1:".";s:13:"thousands_sep";s:1:",";}s:8:"�*�items";a:6:{s:2:"id";i:29;s:4:"name";s:6:"effewf";s:5:"price";d:24524;s:8:"quantity";i:3;s:10:"attributes";O:41:"Darryldecode\Cart\ItemAttributeCollection":1:{s:8:"�*�items";a:0:{}}s:10:"conditions";a:0:{}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the data as JSON and use `$casts` property to make Laravel convert `cart` data from JSON to an array and back automatically:

```
protected $casts = [
    'cart' => 'array',
];
```

So, you will be able to work with `$order->cart` as with an array.

> Once the cast is defined, you may access the attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When you set the value of the attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: ok assuming that I added casts to my orders model. how to I save that quantity from my update function? (I mean show me code for that! please.)

Comment: @mafortis you haven't shown an example of the data, so I can just assume that this is a serialized array. In this case, you'll be able to just do something like this `$order->cart['ihpone']['quantity'] = 2; $order->save();`

Comment: I included a sample to my question.

Comment: I put the code in my question before, blade part (as front end) and code above that as how I unserialized it.